# Thinkpad X240 middle scroll on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xorg, thinkpad

My middle click scroll does not work. It is assigned as paste shortcut (default behavior for middle click). How to fix this?

I already followed guide from [ThinkpadWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint) but it still won't work.

Please help me.